# How to check dynamically with radio box is selected in the div

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

I need a dynamic function  for checking whether a `radio box` is selected in the `div` or not.

Actually I want to show an error message every time an user, without selecting the `radio button`, presses the next button.

I am working on this [page](http://www.gomlekevi.com/indexDESIGN.php). The **ILERI** means  **NEXT**.

These are the divs. There are 9 div on the page cited above.

```
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
    <a id="back"  class="ileri-geri" target="1"  >GERİ</a> <h1>Cep Çesitleri</h1>
    <a  class="ileri-geri" target="3">İLERİ</a>
    <div class="urunler">
        <ul class="urun">
            <li><img src="imagesBOX/items/cepsayisi/0.jpg"></li>
            <li><p>Cepsiz</p><input type="radio" name="cep_cesitleri" value="0" /></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="urun">
            <li><img src="imagesBOX/items/cepsayisi/1.jpg"></li>
            <li><p>Tek Cepli</p><input type="radio" name="cep_cesitleri" value="1" /></li>
            <li></li>
         </ul>

        <ul class="urun">
            <li><img src="imagesBOX/items/cepsayisi/2.jpg"></li>
            <li><p>Çift Cepli</p><input type="radio" name="cep_cesitleri" value="2" /></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

        <h1>Cep Sayisi</h1><br/>


        <?php foreach($Secondresult As $jcRow):  ?>
                <ul class="urun">
                <li><img src="imagesBOX/items/cep_cesitleri/<?php echo $jcRow->image ?>" /></li>
                <li><p><?php echo $jcRow->title ?></p><input type="radio" name="cep_cesitleri" value="<?php echo $jcRow->id ?>" /></li>
                <li></li>
                </ul>
          <?php endforeach; ?>


        </div>



    </div>
   <!----2nd page--->
```

this is javascript which hides all the div and show the div only based on target attribute of  tag .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                          
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
        $('#divfirst').show();
        $(".ileri-geri").click(function(event){
            $('.targetDiv').hide();
            $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).fadeIn('slow');
            //alert("Redirecting you to jQuery.com!");
        });
</script>
```

Now I want that, If user click on `ILERI` button  without selecting the radio option, then the error mesg will appear, but the function should dynamically show that it handles all the 9 div on this page.

Comment: thanks for your answers guys but i want a dynamic function

Comment: I have updated my code, [check and try it please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331719/dynamic-function-for-cheking-whether-is-radio-box-is-selected-in-the-div-or-not/13331818#13331818)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if at least one item was checked with this:

```
$(".urun input:checked").length() > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ileri-geri").click(function(event){
    //you have to detect the visable .targetDiv first
    if($('.targetDiv:visible input:checked').length() > 0) {
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
        $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).fadeIn('slow');
    }else{
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```